# Querying JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am new to working with JSON and I figured out how to query for specific data but how does it work with foreach loops?

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "Example": {
        "Header": [
            [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E",
                "F",
                "G",
                "H",
                "I",
                "J",
                "K"
            ]
        ],
        "Body": [{
                "A": "XY",
                "B": 0,
                "C": 5,
                "D": 2,
                "E": 5,
                "F": 7,
                "G": 3,
                "H": 7,
                "I": 2,
                "J": 7,
                "K": 88
            },
            {
                "A": "XY",
                "B": 4,
                "C": 3,
                "D": 5,
                "E": 8,
                "F": 6,
                "G": 4,
                "H": 2,
                "I": 887,
                "J": 445,
                "K": 4
            },
            {
                                "A": "XY",
                "B": 0,
                "C": 20,
                "D": 32,
                "E": 44,
                "F": 5,
                "G": 50,
                "H": 2,
                "I": 35,
                "J": 10,
                "K": 55
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to get the integers for every zone.

I figured out that I can get a specific data like this (I get the value 0)

```
public void importLocations(JObject locationsObject) 
{
    string test = (string) MyObject.SelectToken("Body[1].A");
}
```

I am trying to get all values back but I was not able to do it. I would appreciate your help.

EDIT: this worked for me:

```
var bodys = MyObject["Body"] as JArray;
int counter = bodys.Count;

for (int x = 0; x < counter; x++) 
{
    foreach(var i in bodys[x]) 
    {
        i.First.Value < string > ();
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

If you know a more elegant option I would be happy to know it too.

Comment: The json you posted isn't valid. Are you missing a closing square bracket for the body?

Comment: Yes, I just copied a part of the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deserialize your JSON to a class and do whatever you want. [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ztfprh)

```
public class Body
{
  public string Abstände { get; set; }
  public int Eingangslager { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Zone A")]
  public int ZoneA { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Zone B")]
  public int ZoneB { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Zone C")]
  public int ZoneC { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Zone D")]
  public int ZoneD { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Zone E")]
  public int ZoneE { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Zone F")]
  public int ZoneF { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Zone G")]
  public int ZoneG { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Zone H")]
  public int ZoneH { get; set; }

  public int Ausgangslager { get; set; }
}

public class LocationDistance
{
  public List<List<string>> Header { get; set; }
  public List<Body> Body { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
  public LocationDistance LocationDistance { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);

    data.LocationDistance.Body.ForEach(body => {
      var propertyInfo = body.GetType().GetProperties();
      foreach (var p in propertyInfo)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " : " + p.GetValue(body));
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject));

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works well if your JSON schema is fixed. It has the advantage making the code easy to read. If the schema might change and you want to avoid having to update more properties than you need, you can try something like this:

```
    var test = locationsObject.SelectTokens("LocationDistance.Body[*]")
            .Select(t => t.Children()
                .Select(c => c.ToObject<JProperty>())
                .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Zone "))
                .Select(t => new { Name = t.Name, Value = int.Parse(t.Value.ToString()) }))
            .ToList();
```